# Invalid URL parser in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

[Yes, the title is not a typo!]

In python I need something that parses a URL. I cannot believe something standard does not already exist. As the URL is set in a config I'd like to make sure it is not garbage.

There's urlparse.urlparse, but that only parses 'valid URLs' (with some invalid URLs sometimes raising an undocumented ValueError)

e.g.

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> urlparse.urlparse('http://aa :: aa ! aa:11.com:aa').netloc
'aa :: aa ! aa:11.com:aa'
```

shows how urlparse parses what I would consider an invalid URL.

Comment: Can't you just use urlparse and catch the errors?

Comment: Whats about a regex? I guees youll find thousands for urls.

Answer (score 2):

URL parsing and URL validation are actually different tasks.

`urlparse.urlparse` makes parsing, validation is usually made using regular expressions machine (built-in `re` module in Python).

Here's and example of URL validation from Django framework:

```
regex = re.compile(
    r'^(?:http|ftp)s?://' # http:// or https://
    r'(?:(?:[A-Z0-9](?:[A-Z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Z0-9])?\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2,6}\.?|[A-Z0-9-]{2,}\.?)|' #domain...
    r'localhost|' #localhost...
    r'\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})' # ...or ip
    r'(?::\d+)?' # optional port
    r'(?:/?|[/?]\S+)$', re.IGNORECASE)
```

Comment: I had assumed there was something standard, preferrable to just cut-n-pasting code.
But, django.core.validators.URLValidator is exactly what I need, thanks :)

Comment: It is almost impossible to write an extensive url validator with regex. so many cases suc as tel: or mailto: are missing. Also IPv6 and  many more...